# Python: some function for args -> *args (similar like those in functools)

Tags: python, functional-programming

I had these implementations:

```
def vecAdd(v1, v2): return tuple(map(add, izip(v1,v2)))
def vecMul(v1, f): return tuple(map(mul, izip(v1,repeat(f))))
```

Those didn't work because `add` (and `mul`) is called like `add((x,y))`, i.e. it only gets one single argument.

Is there some function which basically does the following?

```
def funccaller_with_exposed_args(func):
    return lambda args: func(*args)
```

Maybe this is overkill and overengineered in this case but in general, this can be very important performance wise if you otherwise could lay out a complete heavy loop into pure C code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with [itertools.starmap](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) or [itertools.imap](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap).
`imap` is like `starmap` except that it zips the arguments first.
So instead of calling `izip` yourself, you could just use `imap`:

```
import itertools as it
def vecAdd(v1, v2): return tuple(it.imap(add, v1, v2))
def vecMul(v1, f): return tuple(it.imap(mul, v1, it.repeat(f)))
```